# Is it possible to read and write an annotation into a java file?

Tags: java, regex, file

I have around 1000+ Java files, all have some annotation written on it at class level.

I want to write an utility that would read the annotation value from all the java file and update it if necessary.

I had thought about using File read/write and matching the annotation with some Regex pattern.

Would there be any better way of doing it ?

Comment: you can `use java.lang.Class` to get all annotations.

Comment: I would not trust a regex, you need a good parser for that. Simple example: suppose you check for the text string `"Annotation:"`; then you may add your annotation to the check that checks for `"Annotation"`.

Comment: @VolodymyrLevytskyi: Is it possible to write the annotation into those java file ?

Answer (score 0):

A lot depends on whether you want to do it once, or developing a system to do it repeatedly in the future.

The first case is much simpler, you could use a smart IDE (like Eclipse) to search for all uses of an annotation in your project and then do things manually. Or you can execute a regexp-based search/replace. I often add a dummy comment to each line of use to make the required regexp simpler.

The second case is much harder. A custom Java parser would likely be required.

Comment: For the second case mentioned by @alex-nevidomsky, you can use roaster library (see https://github.com/forge/roaster). We used the lib for generation of meta-model and we're surprised how smoothly it worked.